# What techniques are available to resolve this problem

Tags: c#, .net-core

Imagine you've got two completely separate classes representing a `Dog`. Let's call them `DogA : AnimalA` and `DogB : AnimalB`.

The inherited classes `AnimalA` and `AnimalB` are not in any way linked and inheritance can't be changed. In other words: on paper `DogA` and `DogB` are completely unrelated classes.

Now let's say you want to add a `public void Bark()` method to both `DogA` and `DogB`. *Some* of the logic behind how to make a dog bark is common between `DogA` and `DogB`, but not all of the logic. In other words, copy-pasting from `DogA` to `DogB` isn't possible but still a big portion of the code is duplicated.

Internally you've already split your Bark() method into smaller private/internal methods such as `ValidateCanBark()` `BeginBark()` `WaitBarkEnd()`.

What techniques are available to avoid having duplicated code in this scenario?

I thought about using interfaces with ValidateCanBark(), BeginBark() and WaitBarkEnd() but of course you don't want to expose those methods publicly so interfaces are out of the question. Abstract base classes also since both classes already inherit something completely unrelated.

The three options I've thought of are:

1. Create an interface `IBarkable` which defines `Bark()` and both `DogA` and `DogB` implement, create some internal (extension) methods that accept `IBarkable`, but since the logic isn't 100% the same on both dogs then you'd need to check whether your `IBarkable` object is *actually* a `DogA` or `DogB`. Works, but not pretty.
2. Still create the interface and methods that accept `IBarkable` but also accept an `Action` for the internal methods `ValidateCanBark`, `BeginBark` and `WaitBarkEnd`. Still not exactly pretty.
3. Separate things even further: create a `DogAHelper` and a `DogBHelper` internal classes (which implement IDogHelper, exposing the `ValidateCanBark`, `BeginBark` and `WaitBarkEnd` itnernally) which contain the unique part of the logic needed. Still create an `IBarkable` interface and methods for, but now the method accept not only a `IBarkable` but also a `IDogHelper`. Common bits of code would be contained in this method whereas different bits of code would be defined on the `IDogHelper`.

But I can't help but feel like these options are all limiting and not great, is there a better way to approach this?

And I am leaving this as more of an abstract question because I'm asking for techniques that can be used in situations like this in an attempt to not just help myself but others in the future too.

Comment: Inject a barking service into your classes. Use [Composition and Aggregation](https://dev.to/namvnngu/inheritance-composition-and-aggregation-in-c-3dj8).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes can you provide that as an answer with some concrete code for this example? My third option already uses composition and aggregation btw.

Comment: How will this Bark() function invoked? AnimalA.Bark ? DogA.Bark? Since they are completely different classes, there is no way Bark method will be called without knowing the class. Even extension method will have to accept any object and then check for the type and invoke Bark.

Comment: `Bark()` is defined directly on both `DogA` and `DogB` classes, if you want them to implement an `IBarkable` sure they can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us declare two interfaces:

```cs
public interface IBarkable
{
    void Bark();
}

internal interface IDogHelper
{
    bool CanBark();
    void BeginBark();
    Task WaitBarkEnd();
}
```

Note that `IBarkable` is public, while `IDogHelper` is internal.

Now we can implement the two dog classes like this (I do not inherit from animal classes, since this doesn't make any difference for our problem):

```cs
public class DogA : IBarkable
{
    private readonly IDogHelper _dogHelper;

    public DogA(IDogHelper dogHelper)
    {
        _dogHelper = dogHelper;
    }

    public async void Bark()
    {
        if (_dogHelper.CanBark()) {
            _dogHelper.BeginBark();
            DoSomethingElse();
            await _dogHelper.WaitBarkEnd();
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse() { }
}

public class DogB : IBarkable
{
    private readonly IDogHelper _dogHelper;

    public DogB(IDogHelper dogHelper)
    {
        _dogHelper = dogHelper;
    }

    public async void Bark()
    {
        if (_dogHelper.CanBark()) {
            _dogHelper.BeginBark();
            DoSomethingCompletelyDifferent();
            await _dogHelper.WaitBarkEnd();
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingCompletelyDifferent() { }
}
```

The two dog classes can share the internals of barking through a `IDogHelper` implementation, but they expose only the `Bark()` method publicly.

Then finally we would create an implementation of the dog helper. Since some parts are equal and some differ, we create it as abstract class:

```cs
internal abstract class DogHelper : IDogHelper
{
    public abstract void BeginBark(); // BeginBark is completely different

    public virtual bool ExtraCheck()
    {
        // TODO: (Only in DogA) implement extra check
        return true;
    }

    private bool StandardCheck()
    {
        //TODO: implement standard tests
        return true;
    }

    public bool CanBark() // CanBark has one extra check on DogA
    {
        return StandardCheck() && ExtraCheck();
    }

    public Task WaitBarkEnd() // WaitBarkEnd is exactly the same 
    {
        //TODO: implement
        return default;
    }
}
```

Now a concrete class must implement `BeginBark` which is completely different (as of your comment). The `ExtraCheck` is already okay for the `DogB` variant and can be overridden for `DogA` to implement the extra check. `WaitBarkEnd` has always the same implementation, thus it is neither `abstract` nor `virtual`.

Comment: But this doesn't deal with the fact that the `BeginBark()`, `CanBark()` and `WaitBarkEnd()` implementations although very similar still differ between `DogA` and `DogB`, here you assume they are exactly the same implementations.

Comment: This would work if you had two separate `IDogHelpers`, one for `DogA` and one for `DogB` perhaps with an abstract class behind them for the common parts, but otherwise you still have the same problem (and gain nothing by just having two separate `IDogHelpers` since you still duplicate the code that would have otherwise been directly on `DogA` and `DogB`)

Comment: I don't get the point. If the implementations are different, which code are you duplicating?

Comment: I'd have to share some code for that and apparently that's not a question for SO, got closed before, same way this one got down voted without even a comment as to why :)

But in short: the `BeginBark` is completely different, `WaitBarkEnd` is exactly the same and `CanBark` has one extra check on `DogA`.

But... in the spirit of good code I'm looking for an option that allows me to keep this logic central - how similar they are *could* change in the future as the implementation evolves...

Comment: But you still end up with two different three different `IDogHelpers` - the abstract class, the concrete class for `DogA` and the concrete class for `DogB`. Is that _actually_ better than having (some) duplicated code on `DogA` and `DogB`? This is basically what I said on my 3rd option on the question and on my comment which totally works of course, but it still seems a bit limiting.

Comment: Also if going down this approach (a different `IDogHelper` implementation for each type of `Dog`) then you can also change the interface `IDogHelper` to just expose a `void Bark()` method and both `DogA` and `DogB` just do `Bark()  => _dogHelper.Bark();` -- even if the specifics of the installation of `DogA` and `DogB` base install routine differ since you've got different implementations of `IDogHelper` they should be the ones responsible for handling those cases.

Comment: Well you could drop the `IDogHelper` interface and work directly with the concrete classes deriving from the abstract one. But I think that this mixed approach with abstract, virtual and non-virtual methods is the best we can do. Of course you can also instantiate these helper classes directly inside the dog classes.

Answer (score 2):

regarding #1: In my opinion the extension should contain bark, not the interface, if bark contains shared logic.

```
    public interface IBarkable
    {
        int BarkDurationSeconds { get; }
        void ValidateCanBark();   //for individual logic
    
    }
    class DogA : IBarkable
    {
        public int BarkDurationSeconds { get => 3; }
        public void ValidateCanBark() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    class DogB : IBarkable
    {
        public int BarkDurationSeconds { get => 5; }
        public void ValidateCanBark() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
public static class Extension
{
    //no "check whether your IBarkable object is actually a DogA or DogB"
    public static async Task Bark(this IBarkable dog  )
    {
            dog.ValidateCanBark();
            await Task.Delay( dog.BarkDurationSeconds );
        }
    }

    public class MyTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public async Task MyTest()
            { 
                await new DogA().Bark();
                await new DogB().Bark();
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: But you've already got one problem here: you've made `ValidateCanBark()` public which I don't want. It's an internal implementation, it shouldn't be publicly visible. Which in turn defeats your whole approach: if `ValidateCanBark()` is not on the interface (which would make it public for implementing classes) then you can't call it from an `IBarkable` object

Comment: or your priorities are strange, if you value the type of accessor over avoiding redundant code